# How to get money back from cancelled apple store order (visa)?

Tags: apple-store, itunes-store

Apple has cancelled my order on the the 5th of March. Today is 12th of March and I still haven't got my money back. What should I do in this case?

I'm using visa card.

Comment: Contact the online Apple Store. If you're in the US, call  1-800-MY-APPLE (800-692-7753).

Comment: @David Pearce, I'm not in the US, is there anyway to contact them via e-mail?

Comment: Probably. Go to the web store of your country and towards the top right will be the contact number http://i.imgur.com/uu5b7mB.png. Alternatively, look down in the footer of the page for the Contact Us link.

Comment: @DavidPearce Pearce, I was trying to ship US iPhone with shipito service. But they don't ship to this service, so they cancelled my order.

Comment: See my answer to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to get in contact with the online store team of the country you purchased from. Here's the [ways to contact Apple](http://store.apple.com/us/help/contact) for order enquiries. If you can't call them, during 'normal business hours' you can chat with them.

> ### Chat
>
> Shopping online and have a quick question?
>
> - Our trained Chat specialists may be available to assist you during normal business hours.
> - Simply click the “Chat” button at the top right of the Apple Online Store page.
>
> ### Phone
>
> Have questions? Ask an Apple Store specialist:
>
> - 1-800-MY-APPLE (1-800-692-7753)
> - Open 24 hours a day, 7 days a week